# MovIeTexture not valid type build error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to insert a movie texture in unity onto a cube screen. This is my code to make it play.

```
#pragma strict

 var movTex : MovieTexture;

 function Start () {

    renderer.material.mainTexture = movTex;
    movTex.Play();

 }

 function Update () {

 }
```

When I try to build it to my Android I get a build error:

```
Assets/Scripts/Movie.js(3,14): BCE0018: The name 'MovieTexture' does not denote a valid type ('not found').
```

Does anyone know what may be wrong?

Comment: By the way it run in unity when I play it. I only get build error, when I build to phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use something that doesn't work on Android, if you look up the `MovieTexture` on the unity docs we find:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html

> Movie Textures are not supported on Android. Instead, full-screen streaming playback is provided using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.